# 403 Forbidden on OS X with Apache & Zend Framework

Tags: macos, apache, zend-framework, http-status-code-403, vhosts

I have Zend Framework working with AMPPS on OS X Lion 10.7, but I want to switch over to the preinstalled PHP/Apache. However, it appears that I have a problem with my permissions. I have the following in my `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName zend.local
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
DocumentRoot "/Users/Andy/Dropbox/My own folder/dev/quickstart/public"

<Directory "/Users/Andy/Dropbox/My own folder/dev/quickstart/public">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    #Options FollowSymLinks Indexes # Didn't need it with AMPPS; doesn't help when uncommented
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This exact configuration worked for me on my AMPPS setup. I tried to change the directory and DocumentRoot to a different folder (/Users/Andy/zendtest/public) and it worked. However, when I try to use my Dropbox folder, I get a 403 Forbidden - even if I used the same folder with my AMPPS setup. I am using an admin account in OS X. I have tried the suggestions from similar topics that I could find but without luck.

Comment: Your own folder , has a space in between?

Comment: @KarmicDice Yes, it contains two spaces. I read that as long as I use quotes for the paths, it is no problem. It also worked on AMPPS with spaces. I tested with `/Users/Andy/zend test/public` and it worked, so apparently the problem is not with the spaces. I _guess_ Apache does not have permissions to execute that folder or something, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I have NEVER worked on mac for development but from Linux perspective. I will draft an answer, if it works, well great! if it doesn't let me know in comments of the answer.

Comment: woah! dropbox folder! is it on Sync? If it is on Sync, it might not work because if Dropbox allowed additional protocol execution other than TCP, it would be a MAJOR I mean SUPER MAJOR vulnerability. But, again that is just an `assumption`. Try to remove sync and comment back?

Comment: @KarmicDice I tried to pause syncing (and closing Dropbox) if that is what you meant, but it did not change anything. I guess you are right about the security aspect, but I'd think it would be possible for local development. Also, it didn't give me any problems on AMPPS. I don't know if there is a sensible explanation as to why.

Comment: Let me put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by using a symbolic link (symlink). I set my `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` to `/Users/Andy/Sites/quickstart/public`. Then I added a symlink from the Terminal (the folder `/Users/Andy/Sites` did *not* exist before adding the symlink):

```
cd /Users/Andy/
ln -s /Users/Andy/Dropbox/My\ own\ folder/dev/quickstart /Users/Andy/Sites/quickstart
```

Then I changed the permission of my Dropbox folder, like so:

`chmod 755 /Users/Andy/Dropbox`

If this doesn't work for you, then try searching for "dropbox apache" on Google and try following some of the tutorials about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

As I said earlier if Dropbox allowed additional protocol execution other than TCP, it would be a MAJOR I mean SUPER MAJOR vulnerability. But, again that is just an assumption. But,
I just asked one of the expert working with me. He said, the same from security perspective (collars up) but, he also mentioned that dropbox does not like (dot files). .htaccess, .git, .gitignore, etc... a prefixed dot usually refers to hidden or system file.. Also, the mime-checking would make sure nothing is being remotely been done to hamper dropbox servers.

Over the argument I did say that all dropbox does is create a folder or a shortcut. How is that relevant? To which another expert hearing our conversation intervened and said that it concept of dropbox `folder` is same as concept of a file called `/dev/null` . You move files to dev null or you move files to dropbox, it may be on your system and/or it may just sync over! Dropbox works on a different protocol rather the one which our system understands.

Hope this explains well :)

PS: If you wish to have a application deployed in the cloud so that you do not have to worry about it's backup and downloadable from all. Then, you can try GitHub (which you can connect to your IDE , if it supports) or PHPCloud.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it! It always seemed strange to me that Dropbox and AMPPS had no problems working together. The solution I came up with was to point Apache to `/Users/Andy/Sites/project1` and create a symbolic link from this directory to `/Users/Andy/Dropbox/My own folder/dev/project1`.

Comment: symlinks! Never thought that would work but, again that would still be a hack! I wonder how long we could keep up with that! If it worked for you, am glad :)